# Are three dots (...) used to indicate only ellipsis?

Tags: usage, writing, style

I googled it and found out that three dots (...) in English means "ellipsis",

But in my language, we use three dots quite commonly not only when we use ellipsis but also in the title of an article, and it can have a different connotation depending on each situation.
So title could be like "Youth are struggling... What are the reasons?"

Can I also use three dots like this in the title of an English article?
Or three dots are only used when indicating ellipsis?

Comment: In your example, their use looks like an example of ellipsis to me. It's suggesting a *pause* or some other missing information that hasn't been written.

Comment: DB, your first sentence is really not correct.  The "three dots punctuation mark" does not "mean" ellipsis.  It's usually *named* an ellipsis. (Just as we name " , " a  "comma".)   However, it is often used as a "dramatic pause".   "Fattie has been ... banned from the site."  I would actually suggest it is **more often used** as a dramatic pause than as an ellipsis.

Comment: Here's an example of a handsome SO list member using it in an article title as a kind of "set-up leading to a question" ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032841/firebase-rtd-atomic-move-delete-and-add-from-two-tables

Comment: Note that I used one as a setup leading to an example in ... the previous comment!

Answer (score 4):

It is usual to call three dots "ellipsis" even if there strictly speaking is nothing being omitted.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis)

> Depending on their context and placement in a sentence, ellipses can indicate an unfinished thought, a leading statement, a slight pause, an echoing voice, or a nervous or awkward silence. Aposiopesis is the use of an ellipsis to trail off into silence—for example: "But I thought he was …" When placed at the beginning or end of a sentence, the ellipsis can also inspire a feeling of melancholy or longing.

In your example, it is completely a matter of typographic style, but you would more usually see in print:

- **Youth are struggling -- What are the reasons?**

Comment: but is it okay to use ellipsis in English article title, then? Cause I don't remember seeing ellipsis in the article title. Is it not common?

Comment: @dbwlsld - quite simply, it is OK, but not that common in titles.  But yes, it is totally OK.